# Getting width of $.find() element is zero

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an element to a function to calculate some data. I am using `$.find()` to get the element and using `$.width` to get its width but for some reason it always shows 0. I do not know why. What am I missing?

here is the pass its in an ajax success callback:

```
success: function(data)
{
    var result = jQuery(data).find('.dir_content'); // get element with find here
    var margin_amount = getScreenMiddle(result);    // pass element to function

    result.attr('id', full_path);
    result.css('margin-right', margin_amount);

    if(prev_element != null)
    {
        prev_element.css("margin-right", 0);
    }
    prev_element = result;

    jQuery('.list-inline').append(result);
},
```

and here is the function

```
function getScreenMiddle(elem)
{
    var center_pos = ($(window).width() - elem.width()) / 2 + "px";
                                       // this is always 0
    return center_pos;
}
```

so this function just returns the same value which is wrong. Do I need to pass this another way?

Comment: Have you try wrapping with another $() ? eg. ($(window).width() - $(elem).width()) / 2 + "px";

Comment: unless the element is rendered to the dom the dimension will not be calculated

Comment: You need to append the element first in document and then try

Comment: @ysrb Im sorry I do not understand what would that do?

Comment: @SridharNarasimhan that worked I just put it after the `.append()` please put this as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @zachstarnes i have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First include the result element in DOM document and then try for width

```
success: function(data)
    {
        var result = jQuery(data).find('.dir_content'); // get element with find here
    jQuery('.list-inline').append(result);    
    var margin_amount = getScreenMiddle(result);    // pass element to function

        result.attr('id', full_path);
        result.css('margin-right', margin_amount);

        if(prev_element != null)
        {
            prev_element.css("margin-right", 0);
        }
        prev_element = result;


    },
```